# One Docker-container runned instead of other. Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
   psql:
    container_name: docker_db
    build: database/
    image: andrey1981spb/docker_db

 webapp:
     container_name: docker_test
     build: src/
    image: andrey1981spb/docker_test
    depends_on:
      - psql
```

Dockerfile for psql:

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_DB_PORT : "5432"
ENV POSTGRES_USER dreamwhite
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD Password2020#
ENV POSTGRES_DB test_psql

EXPOSE 5432
```

Dockerfile for wewapp:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8-alpine

ENV PATH_TOMCAT_USERS /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
ENV PATH_MANAGER /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/
ADD config/tomcat-users.xml  /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
ADD config/context.xml /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
ADD test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

All 2 containers run successfully.
But container docker_db contains data from docker_test.
In particular, I see it by docker inspect docker_db. It return environment variables for docker_test.
And on the server uploaded environment variables and other settings for docker_test (instead of docker_db)

Project-structure:

[image: Project-structure]

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think they both the images are getting built from the same dockerfile cause you have not specified the dockerile under the services.
try this

```
version: '3'
services:
   psql:
    container_name: docker_db
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./database/Dockerfile
    image: andrey1981spb/docker_db

 webapp:
     container_name: docker_test
     build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/Dockerfile
    image: andrey1981spb/docker_test
    depends_on:
      - psql
```

Comment: update the question and add your directory structure of the projcet

Comment: I made a change to answer, try the code now and tell me what happens

Comment: Explain your problem again clearly. Also, make sure you are doing docker-compose build before doing docker-compose up

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file in the original question, the two services have different `build:` context directories so this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I done  docker-compose build once more and have got  "Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: .database/Dockerfile" May be, it is a reason...

Comment: mybad, i changed it,. Now try the updated file. Make sure to do build before doing up

Comment: now docker-compose build realised successfully for to containers. But after "docker-compose up"   "Cannot create container for service psql: Conflict. The container name "/docker_db" is already in use by container "5dbbdf2c07f3eb20a60f........."

Comment: Run 'docker system prune -a' and then do build and up

Comment: I deleted existing containers with same names. And the problem is solved. Thank you!